# Add element of array into existing array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm struggling with how to add the element of the array into an array of objects. I have an array of object:

```
0: (20) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
1: (20) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
2: (20) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
...etc
```

And I have an array that contains strings:

```
const titles = ["some title A", "some title B", "some title C"]
```

So my purpose is, I want to make my data like this:

```
[
 {results: my_existing_array_of_object, title: "some title A"},
 {results: my_existing_array_of_object, title: "some title B"},
 {results: my_existing_array_of_object, title: "some title C"},
]
```

How to do that? Thanks in advance

Comment: `titles.map((title) => ({results: resultsArray, title}));` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do some adjustment from the answer of [@StepUp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66822126/14750244)

```js
const titles = ["some title A", "some title B", "some title C"]
const other = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }, { id: 4 }]

const result = other.map(((o, i) => ({results: o,      //add new key
    title: (i < titles.length) ? titles[i]  : ''})))
console.log(result )
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function to get desired array:

```js
const titles = ["some title A", "some title B", "some title C"]
const other = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }, { id: 4 }]

const result = other.map(((o, i) => ({results: o, 
    title: (i < titles.length) ? titles[i]  : ''})))
console.log(result )
```

Comment: Thank you so much it works for me, and I do some adjustments because I need a new key. [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/66822377/14750244)